# How to Generate imageviews at runtime

Tags: android, imageview, parse-platform

I want to display images on ImageViews at run time and am fetching images from Parse.com. I'm able to display images with array of ImageViews which are predefined in my code. like:

```
ImageView ad1,ad2,ad3,ad4,ad5,ad6;
private ImageView[] imgs = new ImageView[5];
ad1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ad1);
    ad2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ad2);
    ad3=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ad3);
    ad4=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ad4);
    ad5=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ad5);
    ad6=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ad6);
     imgs[0] = ad2; 
     imgs[1] = ad3; 
     imgs[2] = ad4; 
     imgs[3] = ad5; 
     imgs[4] = ad6;
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Footer");
     query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
     query.whereEqualTo("Status", true);
        ob = query.find();
     for (ParseObject country : ob) {
         ParseFile image = (ParseFile) country.get("imageFile");
         imgl.DisplayImage(image.getUrl(), imgs[i]);
        i=i+1;
         System.out.println("the urls are"+image.getUrl());

              }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

XML Layout:

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
 android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/ad2"
     android:layout_width="90dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="3dp"
     tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ad3"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ad4"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ad5"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/ad6"
         android:layout_width="90dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="3dp"
         tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there any way so that I do not have to hard-code the ImageViews and it gets generated automatically with the number of parseobjects ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayout container=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Footer");
     query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
     query.whereEqualTo("Status", true);
        ob = query.find();
     for (ParseObject country : ob) {
         ParseFile image = (ParseFile) country.get("imageFile");
         ImageView iv=new ImageView(this);
         imgl.DisplayImage(image.getUrl(), iv);
          container.addView(iv);
        i=i+1;
         System.out.println("the urls are"+image.getUrl());

              }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

also set the id of the LinearLayout and remove all the other ImageViews:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
 android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@+id/container">


    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I dont want to manually set the array of ImageViews to 5 or any number. I want ImageViews to get create automatically as per the images in database.

Comment: that image array of yours in not used check the code inside for loop

Answer (score 1):

In your xml file, remove the ImageViews. And give the linearLayout some id.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
 android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
 <LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

In your activity, define this linearlayout.

//something like this

```
private LinearLayout linearLayout;
```

then, in `onCreate`,

```
linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
```

and then inside for loop (the ParseQuery one),

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(20, 10, 20, 10); //optional you can also set more margins and do lot of stuff here
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context); //context is the activity context say, this
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
imgl.DisplayImage(image.getUrl(), imageView);
linearLayout.addView(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(context_here);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.wrap_content,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.wrap_content);
iv.setLayoutParams(params);
ll_your_main_container.addView(iv);
```

call this is the loop to add number of `ImageView` objects to your main layout.